# Records are not created in test db while testing with rspec in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I am testing my application using rspec after I finished the testing no errors are shown but records are not created in Test db

Comment: It would be helpful if you include more information in your question.

Comment: spec_helper.rb especially. Maybe it includes `database_cleaner` or something, then it's ok that test db is empty. For now this question is kinda "why isn't my code working"

Comment: @zishe In my spec_helper.rb there is no database_cleaner and I just installed only rspec-rails gem

Comment: Do you mean that you're creating a record in a test and don't see it in the same test (which would be strange) or that you don't see the record after the test ends (which is how RSpec behaves by default, by starting a transaction before the test and rolling it back afterwards)?

Comment: yes I got it  config.use_transactional_fixtures  must be set to false to view our test records in db